# How can I forward localhost to domain

Tags: java, dns

I wrote an API with Java Spring boot, added an SSL certificate, and now when I want to send a query, I send it as https://localhost:8443/report, but what I want is to send it as https://abcd/report, how can I do this?

I created `a` record with my IP address and domain through my provider, I was expecting to get a response from https://abcd/report within a few hours but when I sent the request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many things to think about here:

#### Certificate naming

You say `abcd` - it that a placeholder? Or did you really make a certificate for that name?  (That name would work locally but never on the Internet.)

#### Routing

Most people would be working behind a firewall, so does is the IP address your office or cloud server? Have you/can you open port 443 and forward it to your server?

If you don't want to allow traffic from the Internet, etc then the IP needs to be a local address e.g. 192.168.1.xxx...

Then you can simply create a local override for the name resolution from `abcd` -> `192.168.1.xxx`.  If you are using a Linux machine you could configure that in `/etc/resolve.conf`.  Different techniques for Windows/Mac.

#### Diagnostics

Try using a tool such as [cURL](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html) using the `-v` option to get verbose logging of what is happening.